# Field invisible based on parent field Odoo 8

Tags: python, filter, one-to-many, odoo-8, invisible

I need to invisible a column of one2many field based on parent field.
By inheriting account.invoice model i have added a field inv_type. In account_invoice_line i need to make invisible field 'quantity' if inv_type = 'utility'.

I tried below code:

xml:

```
<record id="ams_invoice_form" model="ir.ui.view">
        <field name="name">account.invoice.form</field>
        <field name="model">account.invoice</field>
        <field name="inherit_id" ref="account.invoice_form"></field>
        <field name="inherit_id" ref="ams.3e_invoice_form"></field>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <xpath expr="//notebook/page/field/tree/field[@name='quantity']" position="replace">
                <field name="quantity"  attrs="{'invisible':[('parent.inv_type,'=','utility')]}" />
                <field name="consumed_unit"/>
                <field name="fixed_charge"/>
            </xpath>

        </field>
    </record>
```

It throwing an client error:

```
 Odoo Client Error

 Error: Unknown field parent.invoice_type in domain [["parent.invoice_type","=","utility"]]
```

Please suggest a solution.. thanks..

Answer (score 0):

Really complicated, as a suggestion you can use an attribute that applies in odoo 9:

```
<record id="ams_invoice_form" model="ir.ui.view">
        <field name="name">account.invoice.form</field>
        <field name="model">account.invoice</field>
        <field name="inherit_id" ref="account.invoice_form"></field>
        <field name="inherit_id" ref="ams.3e_invoice_form"></field>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <xpath expr="//notebook/page/field/tree/field[@name='quantity']" position="replace">
                <field name="quantity" invisible="context.get('ok_invisible', False)"/>
                <field name="consumed_unit"/>
                <field name="fixed_charge"/>
            </xpath>

        </field>
    </record>
```

In the invoicing module it has to affect the fields_view_get function, I understand that you want to hide the columns of the invoice product list so it must affect the account.invoice.line object:

```
class AccountInvoiceLine(models.Model):

      _inherit = "account.invoice.line"

      @api.model
      def fields_view_get(self, view_id=None, view_type=False, toolbar=False, submenu=False):
          if self.invoice_id.inv_type == 'utility':
             self = self.with_context(ok_invisible=True)
          else:
             self = self.with_context(ok_invisible=False)

          return super(AccountInvoiceLine, self).fields_view_get(view_id=view_id, view_type=view_type, toolbar=toolbar, submenu=submenu)
```

Answer (score 0):

In Odoo 8.0 I had to implement it a little bit others. It has the same logic in view but I had to use the fields_view_get method of sale.order and it is needed to load the order from its identifier:

```
class SaleOrder(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'sale.order'

    @api.model
    def fields_view_get(self, view_id=None, view_type=False, toolbar=False,
                        submenu=False):
        order = False
        params = self.env.context.get('params', False)
        if params:
            order_id = params.get('id', False)
            if order_id:
                order = self.browse(order_id)

        if order and not order.is_agreement:
            self = self.with_context(hide_agreement_cols=False)

        result = super(SaleOrder, self).fields_view_get(
            view_id=view_id, view_type=view_type,
            toolbar=toolbar, submenu=submenu
        )
        return result
```